# Как записать из консоли в файл в C

Tags: linux, c, файлы, input

Я пытаюсь написать програму (наподобии tee), которая будет из консоли записывать сразу в файл  в цикле, пока не кончится память буфера. Пробовал через `fwrite`, `fputc`, `fflush`. Проблема заключается в том, что я не понимаю почему даные, которые я ввел, не появляются ни в файле, ни на экране.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    //char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    char * buffer =(char*) malloc(sizeof(BUFSIZ));
    char ch;
    FILE * fp;
    int i;

if((fp = fopen(argv[1],"a")) == NULL )
{   
    printf("Can't open \n");
    exit(1);
}


//while((ch = getchar()) != '\n')   
for(i = 0; i< BUFSIZ; i++)
{
    ch = getchar();
    buffer[i] = ch;
    fwrite(buffer,sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer),fp);
    printf("%s", buffer);
}

fclose(fp);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас несколько ошибок.
В вашем варианте с циклом `for` вам нужно забивать весь буфер - но разве вы хотите именно этого? Действительно лучше уж по достижению конца строки, а еще надежнее - посимвольно, с завершением при закрытии потока (^D, кажется, в Linux).

Далее, вы не ограничиваете введенную строку нулевым символом - так что выбрасывается при выводе на экран все подряд, пока *где-то* не найдется нулевой символ.

`buffer` у вас - просто указатель, так что `sizeof(buffer)` вам даст просто **размер указателя** - 4 или 8 байт. в зависимости от разрядности приложения...

Я бы делал так (только нужно еще добавить проверку, что передано имя файла!):

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char ch;
    FILE * fp;

    if((fp = fopen(argv[1],"a")) == NULL )
    {
        printf("Can't open \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(;;)
    {
        if (EOF == (ch = getchar())) break;
        fputc(ch,fp);
        fputc(ch,stdout);
    }

    fclose(fp);

}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Дело в том, что я пытался сделать что то подобное, но с циклом while, и все тщетно. Собственно,вариант, который вы предложили, тоже не записывает в файл. Возможно, я что то упустил?

Comment: Ну, если он решил вашу проблему - помечайте как принятый...

Comment: На счет имени файла. Разве if(fp = fopen(argv[1],"a")) == NULL ) не проверяет имя файла?

Comment: `argv[1]` у вас может быть `NULL`, если вы не передаете аргумент, а клясться, что `fopen` проверяет переданный указатель - я бы не стал - кто его знает, какой стандарт поддерживает ваш конкретный компилятор. Береженого Бог бережет :), да и лучше сразу сообщить пользователю, что он забыл указать имя файла, чем выдать сообщение об ошибке открытия непонятно какого файла...

Comment: Убедили) Проверку добавил, но проблема осталась, в файле не появляется ничего, что мы вводим

Comment: Я перекопошил уже не одну страницу о `putc` и `getcchar`. И вроде как, разобрался в принципе их работы, но всеравно не понимаю, почему в файле ничего не появляется. Перепробовал много вариаций с циклами проверками и считываниями, открытиями файла в разных режимах(w,a,w+,a+). Единственное, что я могу предполодить почему ничего не появляется, так это потому, что символы читаются по одному в переменную `ch`, но мне кажется, что я ошибаюсь.

Comment: Приведенный мною код я компилировал и запускал (ну, с соответствующими `#include`), все работает...

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы построчно прочитать стандартный ввод (stdin) и скопировать его в стандартный вывод (stdout) и в файлы, переданные в командной строке (аналог tee):

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  // open output files
  FILE* file[argc];
  file[0] = stdout;
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    if (!(file[i] = fopen(argv[i], "w"))) {
      fprintf(stderr, "failed to open '%s': %s", argv[i], strerror(errno));
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  // copy input lines to output files
  char line[BUFSIZ];
  while(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin))
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
      if (fputs(line, file[i]) == EOF) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to write to '%s': %s", (i ? argv[i] : "stdout"),
                strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

  return !feof(stdin); // success on eof
}
```

[`fgets()`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgets) читает строчку, [`fputs()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fputs) выводит строчку. Пример:

```
$ cc tee.c -o tee
$ echo abc | ./tee файл1 файл2
abc
```

Обратите внимание, файлы открываются в режиме `"w"` (как это tee делает), то есть содержимое существующих файлов затирается (truncate), прежде чем новые строки в них копируются. Можно добавить поддержку `tee -a` опции, чтобы в конец файла писать, не трогая начало файла.

Код рассчитывает на то, что при нормальном выходе из программы, автоматически закрываются файлы и очищаются соответствующие буферы ввода/вывода. Это значит, что во время работы программы, пока буфер для выходного файла не заполнится, ничего в файл не запишется. Если вы хотите, чтобы сразу появлялся ввод в выводе, то [можно сделать вывод небуферизированным, как это GNU сoreutils' tee делает](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/25030d942d41b9afdc66ead2f4ab04d287242445/src/tee.c#L224) или сразу использовать небуферизированное API как это tee на FreeBSD делает.

[tee на FreeBSD](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/63d5d6c71fb3a729ed88d7d9a690fd523e4b2c9c/usr.bin/tee/tee.c#L112-L124) использует здесь POSIX [read](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html)/[write](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) вызовы. GNU coretutils' tee использует [read/fwrite комбинацию](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/25030d942d41b9afdc66ead2f4ab04d287242445/src/tee.c#L229-L259).

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем. Проблема была в том, что процес я заканчивал с помощью ctrl + C. С помощью ctrl + D все записывается

Comment: Ну, мне остается только показать на *с завершением при закрытии потока (^D, кажется, в Linux)* в моем ответе :)

Comment: вы можете сделать вывод небуферизированным, чтобы не терять данные при Ctrl+C. По ссылке в моём ответе показано как это GNU tee утилита делает.